# GBQ Updating Geography Column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to update a geography column within my table but receiving the error "Syntax error: Parenthesized expression cannot be parsed as an expression, struct constructor, or subquery at [3:23]" Not really sure how to update the geography column at this point.

```
update `project.dataset.locations`

set polygon = polygon((-75.24508 40.23625,
-75.24470 40.23633,
-75.24464 40.23629,
-75.24468 40.23628,
-75.24463 40.23628,
-75.24469 40.23624,
-75.24468 40.23620,
-75.24504 40.23612,
-75.24508 40.2362500,
-75.24508 40.23625))

where external_id = '1234'
```

I also tried to do it with st_geogfromtext but got the "Unclosed string literal" error, but also received the above error when removing the quotes.

```
update `project.dataset.locations`

set polygon = st_geogfromtext(("-75.24508 40.23625,
-75.24470 40.23633,
-75.24464 40.23629,
-75.24468 40.23628,
-75.24463 40.23628,
-75.24469 40.23624,
-75.24468 40.23620,
-75.24504 40.23612,
-75.24508 40.2362500,
-75.24508 40.23625"))

where external_id = '1234'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below

```
update `project.dataset.locations`
set polygon = st_geogfromtext('''polygon((-75.24508 40.23625,
-75.24470 40.23633,
-75.24464 40.23629,
-75.24468 40.23628,
-75.24463 40.23628,
-75.24469 40.23624,
-75.24468 40.23620,
-75.24504 40.23612,
-75.24508 40.2362500,
-75.24508 40.23625))''')
where external_id = '1234'
;
```

this will update respective id to below geography

[image]